# strange behaviour with exception handling

Tags: .net, exception, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-middleware

i have a dotnet core 6 api with a very strange behaviour in exception handling

- there's an exception middleware that should handle all exception in api calls (which is correctly instantiated in app startup)
- there's a filter that makes some common checks and throw an exception if some conditions are not met
- there a specific OnActionExecutionAsync procedure in a controller to make specific checks and throw another exception if conditions are not met

```cs
public class MyFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        if (someCondition)
            throw new SomeException();

        await next();
    }
}

[MyFilter]
public class SomeController
{
    public override async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        await base.OnActionExecutionAsync(context, next);
        
        if (someOtherCondition)
            throw new SomeOtherException();
        
        await next();
    }
}
    
public class ExceptionMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public ExceptionMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, IRequestDataManager requestDataManager)
    {
        try
        {
            await _next(context);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // handle exception
            // if someCondition is met, i expect to have SomeException here
            // but instead if appears that SomeController.OnActionExecutionAsync ignore the exception and continue the execution
            // so, my problem is that:
            // if someCondition AND someOtherCondition are met i get SomeOtherException when i should get SomeException
            // if someCondition is met and someOtherCondition is NOT met i get no exception             
        }
    }   
}
```

the problem is:

if conditions inside the filter are not met an exception is thrown, BUT the execution returns to controller OnActionExecutionAsync and goes on from there

if i debug the code step by step i can see the exception raised inside filter, but then the code return to controller and goes on without problems

how can i raise the exception in the filter and having that intercepted correctly by the exception middleware?

edit: i've put up a github repo with a simple project that shows the problem: https://github.com/pdesterlich/webapitest

Answer (score 0):

The issue is realted with the order of the filters,You may check the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-7.0#override-the-default-order),and modify the order

I tried as below based on your codes:

Filter

```
public class SomeFilter: ActionFilterAttribute
{    
    public override async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {

        var constants = new Constants();

        if (constants.GenerateException)
            throw new Exception("Filter Exception");

        await next();
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
[Route("api/test")]
[SomeFilter(Order = int.MinValue)]
public class SomeController: Controller
{
    public override async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
       
        var constants = new Constants();

        if (constants.GenerateException)
        {
            throw new Exception("Some Controller Exception");
             
        }
        await next();
    }
    
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetScuole()
    {
        return Ok("Hello World");
    }
}
```

When I debug without modify anything:
[image]

just modify the condition in your controller:

```
if (!constants.GenerateException)
```

[image]

just modify the condition in your filter

```
if (!constants.GenerateException)
```

[image]